# Draw a “k-pointed” star where “k” is passed to the program by the user

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I want to draw a K-pointed star where K is pass by user.

I have tried with `turtle` but it does not work:

```py
import turtle

def star(turtle,n,d):
    sum=0
    for i in range(n):
        angle=180.0-180.0/n
        turtle.forward(d)
        turtle.right(angle)
        turtle.forward(d)
        sum=sum+d
    print("Area is",sum)

k=input()
star(200,k,4)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kpoint.py", line 12, in <module>
    star(200,k,4)
  File "kpoint.py", line 4, in star
    for i in range(n):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: You want to parse `input()` to int by `k=int(input())`

Comment: You need to parse the input into an integer to be able to use it as an integer, e.g. using `int(input())`

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that a `str` type cannot be interpreted as an `int`. The `input()` function returns a `str` type. You can fix this problem by converting the `str` type to an `int` using the `int()` function. Do this like so:

`k = int(input())`

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
k = input()
```

to:

```
k = int(input())
```

is necessary, but not sufficient to make this code run.  Other issues include:

- Your calling arguments to `star()` are mismatched with its declared
  parameters.  (I.e. `200` isn't a *turtle*.)
- Your `sum` calculation to compute *area* is wishful thinking.
- This code will only work with odd values of `k`.
- The `angle` can be computed before the loop as nothing in that
  calculation changes.

Putting all this together, we get:

```
import turtle

def star(n, d):
    angle = 180 - 180 / n

    for i in range(n):
        turtle.forward(d)
        turtle.right(angle)
        turtle.forward(d)

k = int(input("Points (odd number): "))

star(k, 200)

turtle.done()
```